# ¿Cómo posicionar mensaje de error del ModelState en la vista?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo una vista en la que quiero que los mensajes de error de cada campo aparezcan debajo del mismo.

La vista es un formulario para cambiar la contraseña, tiene los campos: contraseña actual, nueva y repetir nueva.
Los mensajes de error definidos con Anotaciones y usando el helper @Html.ValidationMessageFor() me aparecen correctamente, pero si por ejemplo, introduzco la contraseña actual mal, el mensaje no me aparece, sin embargo, si incluyo el helper @Html.ValidationSummary() sí que me lo detecta, pero claro, en este caso no me aparece donde yo quiero.

El código de la vista es el siguiente:

```
<div class="card mb-4">
<div class="card-body">
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Manage", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
  {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

     <span>@Html.ValidationSummary()</span>
     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OldPassword, new { @class = "form-label" })
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.OldPassword, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Contraseña" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OldPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewPassword, new { @class = "form-label" })
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Contraseña" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-label" })
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Contraseña" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cambiar contraseña</button>
  }
   </div>
</div>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se me posicione debajo del campo OldPassword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prueba con

```
ModelState.AddModelError("OldPassword", "La contraseña introducida no es correcta")
```

se añadirá el mensaje en el lugar especificado por el primer string (OldPassword).

Si cambias de opinión y quieres que el mensaje aparezca en el "ValidationSummary", bastará con llamar a la misma función AddModelError pero con el primer parámetro siendo una cadena vacía.